# android dalvik verification error: register1 v1 type 0, wanted ref

Tags: java, android, dalvik, smali, verificationexception

I have been learning how to code smali files, and i had created a certain method which takes a string parameter and puts it in the log.Its java equivalent is something like this:

```
public void log(String param){
        Log.d(param, param);
    }
```

And when i smalied it again and signed the apk, i got the following error in the logCat:

```
10-05 21:52:42.081: W/dalvikvm(32021): VFY: register1 v2 type 0, wanted ref
10-05 21:52:42.081: W/dalvikvm(32021): VFY: bad arg 0 (into Ljava/lang/String;)
10-05 21:52:42.081: W/dalvikvm(32021): VFY:  rejecting call to Landroid/util/Log;.d (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
10-05 21:52:42.081: W/dalvikvm(32021): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x71 at 0x0000
10-05 21:52:42.081: W/dalvikvm(32021): VFY:  rejected Lcom/shqipe/worthstream/utils/Utils;.log (Ljava/lang/String;)V
10-05 21:52:42.081: W/dalvikvm(32021): Verifier rejected class Lcom/shqipe/worthstream/utils/Utils;
10-05 21:52:42.081: D/AndroidRuntime(32021): Shutting down VM
```

This is the method in the smali file:

```
.method public static log(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    .registers 2
    .parameter "paramString"
    .prologue


    invoke-static {p1, p1}, Landroid/util/Log;->d(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I

    .line 63
    return-void
.end method
```

Can anyone explain it to me how i can debug this error?

Comment: Disassemble the generated DEX.  Does it look the way you expected it to?

Comment: I disassembled it, and it is exactly as i had expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

p1 is an invalid register in that context. In fact, baksmali should have caught that! :)

With .registers 2 and a single argument, you have registers v0 and v1, with p0 being aliased to v1. p1 would actually be v2, which isn't allowed, per your .registers directive.

What you want is

```
invoke-static {p0, p0}, Landroid/util/Log;->d(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
```

or equivalently

```
invoke-static {v1, v1}, Landroid/util/Log;->d(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
```

---

With respect to how to debug this sort of error, the best thing you could have done would be to look in the dalvik source code for the VFY error strings that you see, and identify exactly what the error message means (i.e. what error condition is it triggered on), and where in the bytecode the error occurs.

For identifying where it the bytecode the error occurs, look at the error lines

```
10-05 21:52:42.081: W/dalvikvm(32021): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x71 at 0x0000
10-05 21:52:42.081: W/dalvikvm(32021): VFY:  rejected Lcom/shqipe/worthstream/utils/Utils;.log (Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

This shows that the error happened in the `Lcom/shqipe/worthstream/utils/Utils;.log (Ljava/lang/String;)V` method, at bytecode offset 0 (i.e. the first instruction). However, in case it's not clear which instruction it is referring to, you can use the -f option to baksmali, which will cause it to add the bytecode offset as a comment before each instruction.

Comment: I'm also slightly confused that this wasn't caught in dalvik earlier. I would have expected an error about the invalid register, before it ever got to the point where it's verifying the register types.

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem, and now its working fine :) I replaced both of the p1 with p0.

Comment: alternatively,can you suggest me what s the best way to learn programming smali files?

Comment: @gkapagunta Good point - I expanded my answer to provide more information about how you could try to troubleshoot this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to JesusFreke's answer, p0 does NOT reference the Java `this` in the example as the function is static. So the arguments start at p0, as JesusFreke said.